# A Lie algebra associated with a one dimensional foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, lie-algebras, foliations

A non vanishing vector field $X$ on  a  manifold is  called "well behaved" if for every non vanishing smooth function $f$ we have $$C(X)\simeq C(fX)$$ This means that the centralizer Lie  algebras $C(X)$ and $C(fX)$ are isomorphic Lie  algebra.

Example: The vector  field $\partial_{x}$ is  a well behaved vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Nonexample: The vector field $y\partial_{x}-x\partial_{y}$ is not a well behaved vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$.

We conclude from the  above  definition that this  concept is  a  "foliation"  concept. That is to every one dimensional foliation tangent to a well behaved vector field  $X$, we  associate a Lie  algebra $C(X)$.

**Two questions:**

> 1.Is there a well behaved vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which foliation is not  topological equivalent to the foliation of the above example  $\partial_{x}$? If the answer is no, is it true to say that every non vanishing vec. field on the plane is well behaved?(Please see the **Note** at the end of this post).
>
> 2.What is  an example of a well behaved vector field on a **compact** manifold?In particular is a Kronecker foliation on tori, a well behaved foliation?

**Note:** More than 10 years ago, if I remember well,  I heard  from a specialist of foliation that "every foliation of the whole  plane is actually well behaved" and he described this lie algebra via extension of some Lie algebra by another one. I really do not remember the details.